# Type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to write a program that adds two rational numbers with structures 
and this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Fraction{
                int numerator ;
                int denominator ;
                };

int mainMenu(void);
struct Fraction readStructure(void); /*this works well*/
struct Fraction add(struct Fractoin num1, struct Fraction num2);/*this doesn't*/

int main()
{
    struct Fraction num1 = readStructure();
    struct Fraction num2 = readStructure();

    struct Fraction result = add(num1, num2) ;

    return 0 ;
}
struct Fraction readStructure(void)
{
    struct Fraction temp;

    printf("-> Enter the numerator : ");
    scanf("%d", &temp.numerator);
    printf("-> Enter the denominator : ");
    scanf("%d", &temp.denominator);
    while(temp.denominator == 0)
    {
        printf("--> Zero in the denominator isn't possible.. try again : ");
        scanf("%d", &temp.denominator);
    }

    return temp ;
}
struct Fraction add(struct Fractoin num1, struct Fraction num2)
{
    struct Fraction temp;

    temp.numerator = (num1.numerator * num2.denominator) +
                     (num2.numerator * num1.denominator);
    temp.denominator = num1.denominator * num2.denominator ;

    return temp ;
}
```

the compiler says it's wrong and gives me those errors + some more warnings..

```
error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete.
error: parameter 1 ('num1') has incomplete type.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Fraction add(struct Fraction num1, struct Fraction num2);
```

Fraction spelling mistake :)

Comment: :D OMG, I didn't notice that at all !
thanks so much

Comment: That too in two places

Comment: @iharob yes sure, I will but after 9 mins like this site says :)

Answer (score 1):

You've put:

```
struct Fraction add(struct Fractoin num1, struct Fraction num2);
```

But it you look at the type of `num1` you'll see that you've spelt Fraction incorrectly. You've got the `i` and the `o` round the wrong way!

Comment: :D this mistake wasted 2h of my time !!
thanks so much